# pageMeta.LastPublicationDate is not updated after page publish

Tags: dxa, caching

We are using DXA and Site 9.1, we have object cache set up with ACTIVE MQ, so as soon as I publish the page cache gets invalidated and i can see changes in pages, but I do have requirement to set up ASP .Net caching based on last published page, so I am reading last published date from pageMeta and code looks like below, but I can see the LastPublicationDate is not updated as soon as i publish successfully. It seems it has some caching settings, but if this is the case then how come page is getting reflected if I don't use below code. SO my question is:

1. Why PageMeta has not recent published date?
2. if this is because of DXA model caching settings then if why my page is getting updated with latest content?

> ```
>  PageModel pageModel = (PageModel)base.EnrichModel(model);
>         PageMetaFactory pageMetaFactory = new PageMetaFactory(WebRequestContext.Localization.Id);
>         string tcmID = $"tcm:{WebRequestContext.Localization.Id}-{pageModel.Id}-64";
>         IPageMeta pageMeta = pageMetaFactory.GetMeta(tcmID);
>         pageModel.SetExtensionData("LastPublishDate", pageMeta.LastPublicationDate);
> ```

Comment: You're using CIL to obtain the PageMeta, so DXA caching cannot be the reason for it not being up-to-date. Maybe there is a problem with objects caching (or the way you configured it) that the PageMeta does not get invalidated when the page is (re-)published.